# . Htaccess rewrite rules are not working In the Zend skeleton framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2, skeleton-code

I have installed the skeleton framework on xampp. I have checked the url working properly and try to navigate, try to navigate to an invalid URL such as http://comm-app.local/12345.I receive following error.

```
A 404 error occurred
Page not found.
The requested URL could not be matched by routing.

No Exception available
© 2005 - 2015 by Zend Technologies Ltd. All rights reserved
```

Comment: any one know answer or any idea please let know?

Comment: Well by the error it seems your problem is related to your Zend routing, and not Apache rewrite.

Comment: its working following url  http://comm-app.local.but add 1234 its showing error

Comment: The error says it can't find a route for that url. You should post your route. Seems like not many people are using the Zend Framework anymore though. It's been an hour and you only got 7 views.